# How to handle new items in ngRepeat model if model starts empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a list (list1) of items, which will be shown in browser via ng-repeat. 
By selecting items from other list (list2) these items can be added to list1.

I wrote a method to add item into model. This works great if list1 is not empty. But if list1 is empty, item will add to model but there is no ng-repeat to handle it.
Sourcecode contains only the HTML-comment:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in list1 -->
```

What should I add to my code to get this ngRepeat working with new items?

Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35nbc0zL/1/) that demonstrate what you want to do, try to click on an item from the List2 it will add it to List1.
We have two lists as the HTML:

```
<h3>List1</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in list1">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
<h3>List2</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in list2" ng-click="ToList1(person)">{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in our Controller, our list1 model must be defined, so when we cat push data to it,

```
$scope.persons = [{name:"john"},{name:"mouhamed"},{name:"emilie"}];
// Initialise list1 as an empty array
$scope.list1 = [];
$scope.list2 = $scope.persons;

$scope.ToList1 = function(person){
  $scope.list1.push(person);  
};
```

The ToList1 function, is triggered on click on one item from List2, it add the object (in ou exemple person) to the list1 model.

---

In the case you are using a controller for each list, you can use the **$rootScope.$emit()** and **$rootScope.$on()** functions to communicate between controllers.

```
function FirstCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.list1 = [];
  // Listener for the list1/add event, that will execute the callback when received a 'list1/add' event
  $rootScope.$on('list1/add', function (event, data) {
    $scope.list1.push(data);
  });
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.persons = [{
    name: "john"
   }, {
    name: "mouhamed"
   }, {
    name: "emilie"
   }];
  $scope.list2 = $scope.persons;

  $scope.ToList1 = function (person) {
    // Emit the 'list1/add' event with the selected person object
    $rootScope.$emit('list1/add', person);
  };
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35nbc0zL/2/) that demonstrate this case.

Comment: We are using a controller for each list. I see in List2Ctrl following code: $scope.list1 = new Array(); when list1.length was 0. That was the problem.

Comment: You can dialog between two controllers via the $rootScope's $emit and $on functions. i've updated my answer with the case when the two lists are not in the same controller